# Angular 2 inject HTML into inline template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, templates

I'm trying to inject html into an inline template.  Mostly because I'm lazy and don't feel like making a component.

I have a an inline template implemented the following way:

```
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let entity of serviceRequests">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-note>[Skill Name]{{skillTypeOptions.resolveName(entity.skillId)}}</ion-note>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-item>
    <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="offerTemplate" [ngOutletContext]="{entity: entity.Offer, title: 'Offer'}">
    </template>
    <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="offerTemplate" [ngOutletContext]="{entity: entity.Counter, title: 'Counter'}">
    </template>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>

<template #offerTemplate let-entity="entity" let-title="title">
  <ion-card>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-note>{{title}}</ion-note>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-note>For {{entity.price}} $</ion-note>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-card-content>
      {{ entity.messageText }}
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</template>
```

is there a way I can pass another template into the template to nest templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.  You just have to pass in the template as a parameter.
First add a parameter to the parent template, `let-footerTemplate="footerTemplate"`:

```
<template #offerTemplate let-entity="entity" let-title="title" let-footerTemplate="footerTemplate">
  <ion-card>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-note>{{title}}</ion-note>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-note>For {{entity.price}} $</ion-note>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-card-content>
      {{ entity.messageText }}
    </ion-card-content>
    <ion-item>
      <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="footerTemplate" [ngOutletContext]="{entity: entity}">
      </template>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>
</template>
```

Then you can display the template variable in the ngTemplate directive again.
and the usage would look like so:

```
<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="offerTemplate" [ngOutletContext]="{entity: entity, title: 'Counter', footerTemplate:footerTemplate}">
</template>
```